# Can Confluent Kafka .NET API connect to Event Hub using Managed Service Identity

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub, confluent-platform

We would like to connect our producers and consumers to our Kafka-enabled Event Hub using the Confluent Kafka .NET API. This works fine if we keep and pass the SAS keys and secrets, but it would be much better if we could use the Managed Service Identity capabilities of Event Hub.

Using MSI when connecting to Event Hub seems pretty easy when using the Event Hub client, but how can we do it when using Kafka clients?